# Data Loss when trying to copy char* in C

Tags: c, memcpy, strcpy, strncpy

I have been working on a project in C and I am having trouble when trying to copy char* using strcpy/memcpy/strncpy, none of these seem to work. The problem that is arising is that the words that are around 8 or more characters long are not being copied completely.

```
typedef struct wordFrequency {
    char * word;
    int frequency;

struct wordFrequency *left, *right;
} *node;


node setnode(char * word) {

    node newNode = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(word));

    strcpy(newNode->word, word); //This is where I'm having trouble

    newNode->frequency = 1;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

The code above is what I believe is the main cause for error, but I don't know where to fix it. I have tried messing with the sizes, but that didn't work.

If possible can someone explain to me a way to copy all characters or if I did not allocate enough space?

Comment: `node newNode = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));` is not correct. Suggest avoiding pointer typedefs and using standard `malloc` patterns

Comment: Chuckling "`strcpy/memcpy/strncpy`, none of these seem to work..." -- when that thought even passes by in your mind, it isn't `strcpy/memcpy/strncpy` that isn't working.... `:)` You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Comment: `sizeof(node)` is `sizeof(a_pointer)` and `sizeof(word)` is `sizeof(a_pointer)` generally 8-bytes on x86_64 and 4-bytes on x86. Is that going to be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how to properly allocate and initialize each node in your linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) \
    (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

typedef struct wordFrequency {
    char *word;
    int frequency;
    struct wordFrequency *left, *right;
} node;

node *setnode(char *word) {
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->word = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(newNode->word, word);
    newNode->frequency = 1;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int main() {
    char *wordList[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    node nodeHead;
    node *nodePrev = &nodeHead;
    node *nodeNext;
    for (int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE(wordList); index++) {
        nodeNext = setnode(wordList[index]);
        nodePrev->right = nodeNext;
        nodeNext->left = nodePrev;
        nodePrev = nodeNext;
    }
    for (node *nodePtr = nodeHead.right; nodePtr != NULL; nodePtr = nodePtr->right) {
        printf("word = %s, frequency = %d\n", nodePtr->word, nodePtr->frequency);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
word = one, frequency = 1
word = two, frequency = 1
word = three, frequency = 1
```

**Note**

This program has no error checking and does not free the allocated memory. This code should not be used in a production environment.

**Replies to Questions in Comments**

I replaced `*node` with `node` in the `typedef` because that allows me to declare instances of `node`. The other syntax only allows pointers to `node`.

I use an instance of `node` instead of `node *` for `nodeHead` because any attempt to change its address will be an error.

I use `nodePrev` to traverse the list and also to provide a target for `left` in the returned nodes. I initialize `nodePrev` to `&nodeHead` because it is the start of the list. I set `nodePrev` to `nodeNext` because that's how I chose to traverse the list during initialization. I could have used

```
nodePrev = nodePrev->right;
```

and achieved the same effect.

I only implemented list handling so that I could create a self-contained example that would run without changes. You can safely ignore it.

If you want to see good linked list code, I recommend [the linux kernel implementation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h).

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look this through, I will get back to you when I finish. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Okay ... it worked ... took some tinkering, but it worked. Now if it's okay with you I am going to try and decipher the reason below and I was wondering if you can tell me if I'm in the right place?

Comment: What's "the reason below"?

Comment: So when creating the struct you gave it the name "node" opposed to me naming it "*node" which I was under the assumption meant a pointer to node. Then you created "nodeHead" using node and gave "*nodePrev" the address of "nodeHead." From there you created a for loop that would run for the amount of strings in the array "wordList." You then used setnode on "nodeNext", using that set "nodePrev->right" to "nodeNext" and nodeNext->left" to "nodePrev". Im not really sure why you did the second part or the third part, which is setting nodePrev = nodeNext.

Comment: I did my best to answer your questions. My recommendation would be to ignore my list handling code. I only added it so that I could create a stand-alone example.